# d3.js tree layout is bunching everything up at the top

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3js to create a tree graph with two nodes connected to each other. My JS is as follows:

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var nodes = [{"id":"1","name":"a"},{"id":"2","name":"b"}];
var links = [{"source":0,"target":1}];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
svg.attr("width", width);
svg.attr("height", height);
svg.append("svg:g");

var tree = d3.layout.tree();
tree.size([width, height]);
tree.nodes(nodes);
tree.links(links);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  node.append("text")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

So I'm setting the width and height of the SVG equal to the window width / height. And yet everything is bunched up at the top right.

My JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eeLfog4m/1/

Any ideas?

What'd be helpful is a d3js demo without all the bells and whistles. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550 rotates everything around the center. http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092 seems to have a lot of extra code for handling redrawing / collapsing of nodes and https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout doesn't have any examples at all.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing everything squished at the top-left corner is because all attributes are either `NaN` or `undefined`. This is because you are using

```
.projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });
```

and

```
.attr("transform", function(d) { 
         return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; 
 });
```

which is accessing `d.x` and `d.y`, which are undefined.

Ideally, `d.x` and `d.y` are generated by the layout algorithms like `d3.layout.tree()`. However, in the code you provided, the data that you are passing into the tree-layout algorithm is incorrect.

`d3.tree.layout()` expects a hierarchical data structure, whereas you are providing it links and nodes, which will not work without some major workaround. If you want to use tree-layout, I suggest you convert your data into a hierarchical structure and then visualize it. Here is an example of doing that

```
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

var root = {
 "name": "1",
 "children": [
  {"name": "2"}
 ]
};

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
          .size([width, height-40]);

var nodes = tree.nodes(root);
var links = tree.links(nodes);

var path = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y;  });

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 2);
      .attr("d", function(d){
        return path([d.source, d.target])
      });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + (d.y + 20) + ")";       })

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5);

  node.append("text")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

If however, you want to stick with the current data format:

```
var nodes = [{"id":"1","name":"a"},{"id":"2","name":"b"}];
var links = [{"source":0,"target":1}];
```

you should use force-directed layout.

Here is an example of using force-directed layout with the data structure you have (http://jsfiddle.net/ankit89/3kL11j6j/)

```
var graph = {
 "nodes": [
     {"name": "Leo"},
     {"name": "Mike"},
     {"name": "Raph"},
     {"name": "Don"},
     {"name": "Splinter"}
],
"links": [
    {"source": 0, "target": 4, "relation": "son"},
    {"source": 1, "target": 4, "relation": "son"},
    {"source": 2, "target": 4, "relation": "son"},
    {"source": 3, "target": 4, "relation": "son"}
]}


var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .size([400, 400])
    .linkDistance(120)
    .charge(-30)
    .start();


 var svg = d3.select("svg");

var link = svg.selectAll("line")
.data(graph.links)
.enter().append("line")
.style("stroke", "black");

var node = svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("r", 20)
.style("fill", "grey")
.call(force.drag);

node.append("title")
.text(function(d) { return d.name; });

force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
})
```

And finally, you do not necessarily need d3 layouts, you can even use your custom layout like this

http://jsfiddle.net/ankit89/uts5orrd/5/

```
var graph = {
 "nodes": [
     {"name": "Leo", "level": 1},
     {"name": "Mike", "level": 1},
     {"name": "Raph", "level": 1},
     {"name": "Don", "level": 1},
     {"name": "Splinter", "level": 2}
],
"links": [
    {"source": 0, "target": 4, "relation": "son"},
    {"source": 1, "target": 4, "relation": "son"},
    {"source": 2, "target": 4, "relation": "son"},
    {"source": 3, "target": 4, "relation": "son"}
]}

 var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr({
    "cx": function(d, i){
        var x;
        if(d.level == 1){
            x = i*100 + 100;
        }else{
            x = 250;
        }
        d.x = x;
        return x;
     },
    "cy": function(d, i){
            var y;
            if(d.level == 1){
                y = 260;
            }else{
                y = 60;
            }

            d.y = y;
            return y;
        },
    "r" : 30,
    "fill": "gray",
    "opacity": .5
})

svg.selectAll("text")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter()
.append("text")
.attr({
    "x": function(d){return d.x},
    "y": function(d){return d.y},
    fill: "steelblue"
})
.text(function(d){
    return d.name;
})


svg.selectAll("line")
.data(graph.links)
.enter()
.append("line")
.attr({
    "x1": sourceX,
    "y1": sourceY,
    "x2": targetX,
    "y2": targetY,
    "stroke-width": 2,
    "stroke": "grey"
})

function sourceX(d, i){
    var t = graph.nodes[d.source].x;
    return t;
}

function sourceY(d, i){
    var t = graph.nodes[d.source].y;
    return t;
}

function targetX(d, i){
    var t = graph.nodes[d.target].x;
    return t;
}

function targetY(d, i){
    var t = graph.nodes[d.target].y;
    return t;
}
//console.log(graph.nodes)
```

Here is the gist of the story:

1. If using d3 layout, make your data structure match the data-structure expected by the layout and d3 will compute the x and y coordinates for you.
2. If using want a custom layout, write function to determine the x and y coordinates for nodes and the links.